# Transform data from fetch with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, react-hooks, axios

I have retrieved data from an API, and now trying to transform the data to send a POST request. I want to group two User ID's that match, and POST their common cities in a array instead of separate objects.

For example, data I retrieve looks like this:

```
{
    "events": [
         {
             "city": "city-1",
             "user": "d1177368-2310-11e8-9e2a-9b860a0d9039"
         },
         {
             "city": "city-2",
            "user": "d1177368-2310-11e8-9e2a-9b860a0d9039"
         }
]}
```

I want my POST request data to look similar to this:

```
{
    "user": {
        "d1177368-2310-11e8-9e2a-9b860a0d9039": [
            {
                "city": [
                    "city-1",
                    "city-2"
                ]
            }]}}
```

So far this is my React component for the request:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "../data/axios";

export default function Events({ fetchEvents }) {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const requests = await axios.get(fetchEvents);
      setEvents(requests.data.events);
      return requests;
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchEvents]);

//here is my issue:
  function createSessions(user, city) {
    if (user === user) {

    }
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a codewriting service. What have you tried already on your own? See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Where do the `area` and `total` property values come from?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: That looks like the code to get the `events` array. There were you've marked where the issue is, what is the issue? What can we help with there?

Comment: I want to create a function that adds the matching IDs into an array. Then I want to POST the new manipulated data

Comment: How would I convert the data?

Comment: `events` is an array. You could use array functions to convert it to a form more suitable for your POST request. Do you want to try something first?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the `events` array, reducing it into an object with a `user` object property. The `user` object has the `user` values from the `events` array elements as key and the cities are pushed into a `city` array property.

```
events.reduce(
  (result, el) => {
    if (!result.user[el.user]) {
      result.user[el.user] = [{ city: [] }];
    }
    result.user[el.user][0].city.push(el.city);
    return result;
  },
  { user: {} }
);
```

```js
const data = {
  events: [
    {
      city: "city-1",
      user: "d1177368-2310-11e8-9e2a-9b860a0d9039"
    },
    {
      city: "city-2",
      user: "d1177368-2310-11e8-9e2a-9b860a0d9039"
    }
  ]
};

const data2 = data.events.reduce(
  (result, el) => {
    if (!result.user[el.user]) {
      result.user[el.user] = [{ city: [] }];
    }
    result.user[el.user][0].city.push(el.city);
    return result;
  },
  { user: {} }
);

console.log(data2);
```